# Why have there been no birth defects to all children born of close relative marriages?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones, realism, house-of-the-dragon

It is well known that children born of close relative marriages are very likely to have birth defects.

But all children in the ***Game of Thrones*** universe do not suffer any birth defects, given they are born from the King Slayer and his sister or they are born from Daemon and Rhaenyra.

Is there any rational explanation of this practice? Given Hemophilia as a well-known disease as a consequence of close relative marriage.

Comment: I'd say this entire question is based on a false premise. Though no-one of these times knows anything about genetics other than 'colour of hair', 'Insanity' is the one thing known to be increasing in both the Targaryens & Lannisters. [GoT Fandom has a decent précis](https://gameofthronesfanon.fandom.com/wiki/Incest) Haemophilia is not in itself a consequence of incest, but as it's a recessive gene, it's one way of its having been reinforced through the European Royal families.

Comment: Plus this is a fictional world. That can always be presented as a reason for things being different.

Comment: @Tetsujin The first part seems like an excellent answer.

Comment: This is a setting where multiple thousands of people are returned from the dead under psychic control, where dragons with the traditional form are viable creatures for battle, and magic is a legitimate phenomenon (in multiple forms at that). Questioning how incest can avoid genetics that may not even exist is not a useful question for this site.

Comment: @Nij, yes, it is also a world where people speak from their mouths and think with their brains.

Comment: Yes, the emergent capability of what appear to be humans is surprisingly similar, given how the laws of physics are so significantly different.

Comment: The problem is that the two series directly contradict one another on the hair color issue. In the new series the young brown haired queen has two white haired children which undermines the whole hair color issue of both Rhaenyra's children and the Later Lannisters. So the sci-fi magic handwave does not work for the people who live in that world: it is a diagetic problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*After comments*
I think the question is based on a false premise, that there are 'no defects'.
'Insanity' is a 'defect'.

It is well-known to us today and we also know the reasons why.
Even if Game of Thrones wasn't set in a fictitious world, it has a technology level perhaps 500 to 1,000 years prior to the discovery of the gene. [They have no gunpowder, which puts it pre 13th century as a European equivalent.]

There is evidence they understand breeding and animal husbandry, if not the mechanisms behind it, and indeed some of the consequences. They are aware that hair colour is affected by that of the parents - Ned Stark's investigation into the Baratheon [Lannister] children's hair colour, for instance. They know the dragons are getting smaller over time, but it is not [as far as I can recall offhand] explained why.

There is also clear evidence, in character-revealed back story, as to the increasing insanity in the Targaryen dynasty as a result of their intermarriage, and again in that of the Baratheon/Lannister children.

There is a good précis of this on [GoT Fandom.](https://gameofthronesfanon.fandom.com/wiki/Incest)

Haemophilia is not in itself a consequence of incest, but as it's a recessive gene, it's one way of its having been reinforced through the European Royal families.

Comment: Moreover, Targaryens have some level of magic in them. In plenty of cases they are shown to swiftly recuperate from wounds, for instance. They're also the only ones who can ride dragons and are somewhat telepathically connected to them, and dragons are connected to magic as well. (See also: prophetic dreams,...) Perhaps this magic is helping in reducing the effects of inbreeding.

Comment: I would consider replacing the provided link with [this one](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Incest) since the one you provided is for the fanfic wikia, containing examples from both canon sources and fan fiction.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the question is based on a false premise. There are a lot of defects in the Targaryen bloodline, even beyond insanity.

Mild spoilers beyond this point.

- White hair and purple eyes could count as defect.
- A lot of Targaryens are born with 6 fingers and toes. I don't think this is ever mentioned/alluded to in the TV shows (yet), but finger abnormalities are a common consequence of inbreeding.
- There were a few occurrences of monstrous children. If you accept Tyrion Targaryen theory, you have here a prime example (it is in fact one of the main arguments of the Tyrion Targaryen theory), but even within the official Targaryens, there are quite a few disfigured children (and thankfully stillbirths). I'll try to add examples later.
- Even with 'normal' children, you have still a great amount of stillbirths and difficult births (twice in "House of the Dragon" they had to cut open the mother). It might be a standard issue for the time period. Or it might not. In the great houses (with access to maesters), there are not a lot of mentions of stillbirths. Except for the Targaryens.
- The question mentions hemophilia. Did you watch "House of the Dragon"? Did you see what happened to king Viserys from a mere 'paper cut' (sword paper cut, but still a paper cut)? You can say all you want that Maester 'healing' (leaching, lancing) did not help, but, in universe, it's still considered good enough for other people.

Comment: "White hairs and purple eyes could count as defect." No they can't. Those are Valyrian traits: https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Purple_eyes

Comment: Regarding Tyrion even without the theory part he can still be affected as Lannisters tend to breed within quite a small gene pool as well - they often marry between quite close relatives or with their Lannisport counterparts. Tyrion's mother and father were first line cousins, which while not considered incest is still a very close family relation.

Comment: @BCdotWEB : same as 6 fingers... But did those became Valeryan traits thanks to centuries of inbreeding, or did the inbreeding kept those recessive traits ?

Comment: @dna https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Valyria mentions nothing about incest. Targaryens most likely practice it to keep their blood "powerful", possibly assuming that too much "dilution" would impede their connection to dragons etc.

Answer (score -1):

> It is well known that children born of close relative marriages are very likely to have birth defects.

*More* likely yes; *very* likely no.

> …
> For the most part, scientists studying the phenomenon worldwide are finding evidence that the risk of birth defects and mortality is less significant than previously thought.
> …
> Historically, marriage between cousins has been seen as desirable in many parts of the world, and even today, slightly more than 10 percent of marriages worldwide are between people who are second cousins or closer,
> …
> — [Beyond Kissing Cousins: Marriage Taboos Erode - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/11/26/garden/26cousins.html)

> Consider Queen Cleopatra of Egypt, whose ancestry is well documented.
> For five generations back, all of her ancestors descended from the same couple.
> Most people have 64 great-great-great-great-grandparents.
> Cleopatra had only 2.
>
> If that's not an incestuous family tree, I don't know what is.
> Yet no one says "So that's why Cleopatra was so deformed!".
>
> Yes, if someone has a broken gene and their descendants interbreed, there is a greater chance that a child will end up with two copies of that gene.
> But the risk usually isn't high.
> When it does happen it typically means that that child won't have children of its own, thereby reducing the incidence of the bad gene from the gene pool.
> Except for the obvious case of the child itself, this is a good thing.
> …
> If we applied the same criterion to Down's Syndrome, we would have to make it illegal for women over 32 years old to conceive children, as the percentage of 16-week fetuses with Down's Syndrome is higher than .25% for 33 year old mothers.
> And perhaps we would have to make it a criminal offence for any woman over 42 years old to conceive, as the chances then are ten times higher than that.
> … and more …
>
> — My answer to [Issue comprehending Genesis and the Great Flood - Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72094/issue-comprehending-genesis-and-the-great-flood/72098#72098)